# Is CiviCRM available with German admin interface?

Tags: localisation

Looking at using CiviCRM in an office based in Germany with German-speaking staff. Is there a localised version available, e.g. admin interface in German?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, for more information about downloading translations please see: https://civicrm.org/download-translations

The installation instructions for localized versions vary depending on the CMS you will be using. But full information can be found here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades

Comment: Excellent, thank you. We'll be using WordPress

Answer (score 4):

You can changed the language by including `l10 packages` under directory;

civicrm/l10 and with following;

```
Administer->Localization->Language,Currency,Location
```

I addition;

Also you can set the Default Language`,`currency`,`country and states